# 3D reconstruction using Kinect

Tags: c#

I am doing my final year project on Kinect.Constructing 3d image from depth and color image.I got color and depth image.How to merge them to get 3d image.I am using Visual studio 2010, sdk 1.8, and C#.How to generate 3d image?

Comment: This question is too broad, you need to ask a specific question

Comment: Are you trying to register depth image with the rgb image or stitch multiple point clouds (obtained from depth images)  from multiple view points?